# multi language dynamically in ionic application - google translate

Tags: ionic-framework, translate

I have a application for woocommerce that get data from wordpress
I want add multi language to application that when I choose to English, change all application and products name to english.. can you help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: If you are using ionic+angular, you can try the ngx-translate:https://www.codeandweb.com/babeledit/tutorials/how-to-translate-your-angular-app-with-ngx-translate